# All of my USB flash drives are read only

Tags: usb, flash

All of my USB flash drives are in read only when I connect to my computer. I'm just trying to put a few files from my computer onto a flash drive.

I have done this before successfully but no matter what flash drive I put in I cannot drag the files over to the flash drive. It is in read only.  I have restarted my computer and done `sudo nautilus` but that does not work.

I'm not a heavy user and my in depth ubuntu knowledge is low. If you decide to assist please explain it like I am in kindergarten :)

I don't think this has anything to do with the actual flash drives. I think the problem is with the operating system or the computer. 
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

*I attached a screenshot of what the flash drive looks like in disks (old copy of fedora on there)

[flash drive image in disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhZRi.png)

Comment: In which file system are those drives formatted? FAT, exFAT, NTFS?

Comment: @Michal When I right click on the drive and look into properties it does not say the file type. I just tried to format the flash drive but received this error message "This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition table; please reinitialize layout of the whole device. (udisks-error-quark, 11)"

Comment: There is something wrong with either the partition table (msdos/MBR or GPT) or with the partition itself (FAT, ntfs, ext, etc). In either case, backup your USB stick data on another medium (hard-disk, cd, etc) and open (Gnome) Disks. Click on USB stick icon and choose create a new partition table: msdos/MBR style. After that, create a new FAT partition on that USB stick. Safely eject the USB stick and then reconnect it. Try to write some files on the USB stick. Tell me if it works.

Comment: @ipselute I did exactly as you said but when I tried to move things to the newly formatted thumb drive I get "Error while copying to “63 GB Volume”.  This destination is read-only"

Comment: Have you rebooted? Seems a lot of ppl have solved this with a simple reboot

Comment: @ILOVEKODI It is working!!!!  Thank you everyone! My life can proceed :)

Comment: @Nick: I don't understand! If you formatted the ENTIRE usb drive, how come there are 3 partitions on it? When you format the entire drive all partitions are gone. Anyways, the current configuration of your drive seems somewhat wrong: the EFI partition should always be first, because it holds the partition table records (the data about ALL partitions). I don't even know what partition 3 is all about! How did you created those partitions? Did you use the `dd` command? When you use `dd` command, you are doing a raw write of ISO file to usb and the empty space remains unusable.

Comment: @ipselute I formatted the drive after I posted that picture, sorry for the confusion :)
I don't exactly know what happened or how I got to that point. But I followed your directions and restarted my computer and everything appears to be working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome. Please add the exact procedure (you did) in the answer section and mark question as solved, so others may benefit from your experience. Sharing is carrying.

Answer (score 3):

I opened up the disks program and clicked on the USB stick icon and choose create a new partition table: msdos/MBR style. After that, I created a new FAT partition on the usb stick. I safely ejected the USB stick and then reconnect it. It didn't work initially but I restarted my computer and everything is working perfectly. I am now able to add items to my usb stick.